# have batch complete same task as a switch enabled /p LNK?

Tags: batch-file, switch-statement, autocad, lnk

I have a standard procedure using batch which clears a data application folder, then without exception and always it opens a program with a /p switch BTW I’m not sue if /p switch is an AutoCAD specific thing, however its for AutoCAD this switch can be manually added to the shortcut however I would like the batch to do all this is that possible.

Is it possible to have a batch launch a program using a switch like is possible with an LNK shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The /P switch is an AutoCAD argument. It is for loading an user profile. To launch a program from a batch file with an argument, I think you can use cmd /c or start.